# How to count in vector of vectors

Tags: c++, stdvector

How can I use `std::count` to count in vector of vectors based on the 2nd values of the innermost vectors?

I declare the vector as:

```
vector< vector<int> > distance(data.size(),vector<int>(3));
```

Comment: What is "2nd values of the innermost vactors"?

Comment: They are just integers.

Comment: For one, replace fixed-length vectors with `std::array`: Reduced memry-consumption and enhanced performance.

Comment: @Deduplicator: "enhanced performance" is questionable.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Hm. An expected `data.size()` fewer allocations is questionable optimization?

Comment: @Deduplicator: `std::vector` is generally less expensive to move than `std::array`. Probably not in the case of 3 ints, but you made a general blanket statement.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: But the OP is pre-allocating all the space for the containing vector on creation, so moving does not happen at all.

Comment: @Deduplicator: This is one line of code. You have no idea how this vector is used.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: There's also "locality of reference", "far reduced amount of bookkeeping-overhead" and "simpler access (low-level)". Also, it seems unlikely the vector will ever be re-sized at all, considering that it's used to save the whole data-set for manipulation. In the end, it is a win in nearly every case, even if it is changed. Of yourse there are exceptions, but aren't there always?

Comment: @Deduplicator: You'd need some actual data in order to convince me that it is a win in nearly every case, or even most cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `std::count` for that. You can use `std::count_if`.

```
std::count_if(distance.begin(), distance.end(),
    [](vector<int> const& v) { return v[1] == whatever; });
```

Comment: I so like C++1y auto-parameters. That cannot become commonly available fast enough.Would make things even simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it (that is `std::count_if`)the same way as for "one-dimensional" vectors.

For example

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

//,,,

int value = SomeValue;

auto n = std::count_if( distance.begin(), distance.end(),
                        [&value] ( const std::vector<int> &v )
                        {
                           return v.size() >= 2 && v[1] == value;
                        } );
```

Take into account that sometimes it is more appropriate to use algorithm `std::accumulate` declared in header `<numeric>` instead of algorithms `std::count` and `std::count_if`.